# Why isn't my active tab styling being applied?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tabs and it is working perfectly. I have added border color  as green to active tab using CSS but when I was clicking a tab border color green as blinking. How could I set border color permanent for active border.

I have tried below codes

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#firstTab">View All</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#secondTab">Add New</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="firstTab" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        Tab 1 Content
    </div>
    <div id="secondTab" class="tab-pane fade in ">
        Tab 2 Content
    </div>
</div>
```

css file

```
ul.nav.nav-tabs {
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

ul.nav.nav-tabs li:not(.active) a {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    color: grey;
    }

ul.nav.nav-tabs li:active a {
   border-top: 30px solid #16a765;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "blinking"? Also, this is primarily an opinion, but why do you have the `:not` selector? Why not just style the `a` in the `li` all the same and then adjust the `a` with updated properties when the `li` has an `.active` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the `:active` pseudo-selector (generally associated with links and buttons) with the `.active` class that Bootstrap applies to the currently-selected tab.

```
ul.nav.nav-tabs li.active a { /* <-- dot, not colon */
   border-top: 30px solid #16a765;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. Hope it will help you. I've added some code at bottom of the css file. And they are indicated using comment.

```css
ul.nav.nav-tabs {
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

ul.nav.nav-tabs li:not(.active) a {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    color: grey;
    }

/* My code starts here */
ul.nav.nav-tabs li {
   border-top: 5px solid transparent;
}

ul.nav.nav-tabs li.active {
  border-top: 5px solid #16a765;
}
/* My code ends here */
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#firstTab">View All</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#secondTab">Add New</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="firstTab" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        Tab 1 Content
    </div>
    <div id="secondTab" class="tab-pane fade in ">
        Tab 2 Content
    </div>
</div>
```